# Output of coeffs() into vector format

Tags: matlab

The output of coeffs is symbolic expression vector, despite entries being the numbers. Is there a way to convert this symbolic expression into a vector form with numbers?

Comment: Try casting the result using `double`. `double(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the result to `double`: `double(...);`<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1: Made this Community Wiki to clear up the unanswered queue</sup>